# JPA: many-to-many relation not being mapped

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have 2 classes, many-to-many relationship between them. Classes are Client and Role:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="iq_role")
public class Role extends IdEntity {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "roles")
    private Set<Client> clients = new LinkedHashSet<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="iq_client")
public class Client extends DeletableEntity {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "iq_client_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="iq_client", referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="iq_role", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
}
```

when I select a specific client and join fetch his roles, this is the SQL (generated by Hibernate):

```
select
  client.id,
  role.id
from
  iq_client client
  left outer join
    iq_client_roles client_roles
      on client.id = client_roles.iq_client
  left outer join
    iq_role role
      on client_roles.iq_role = role.id
where
  client.id=1
```

in table `iq_client` I have record with ID 3, in table `iq_role` I have record with ID 1 and in table `iq_client_roles` I have record 3,1.
When I copy this generated SQL and run it from console, I get correct result, but hibernate is not able to map the result into objects obviously.
Any idea why?

Comment: The configuration looks correct . Try using eager fetch strategy. also check the association table data.

Comment: I tried using eager fetch, same result. Association table has one record with IDs of both records from role and client.

Comment: What about the where clause in the generated Query . The ID should be equal to 3 instead of 1 correct.?

Comment: that's right. I made a mistake copying it here. Point is, this SQL is correct, gives correct result. But when I check the object, data is not there.

Comment: What if you remove the **, referencedColumnName = "id"**? And the **= new HashSet<>()** initialization.

Comment: @JoinTable(name = "iq_client_roles", joinColumns ={ @JoinColumn(name="iq_client")}, inverseJoinColumns ={ @JoinColumn(name="iq_role")} One more attempt with { and } because it's an array

Comment: What does the "... when I select a specific client and join fetch his roles, this is the SQL ..." query look like?

Comment: I use queryDSL, so it looks like this:
from(qClient)
                .leftJoin(qClient.roles, qRole).fetch()
                .where(qClient.foreignId.eq(foreignId).and(qClient.deleted.isNull()).and(qClient.partner.eq(partner)))
                .singleResult(qClient);

Comment: but I included generated SQL query in the question